# "PropertyID does not exist in the table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Struggling to see what the issue is with adding a foreign key to the Agents table. I'm getting the error "PropertyID does not exist in the table". Here is the relevant code:

```
CREATE TABLE Properties (
PropertyID INT(8),
Address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Level TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
PropertyValue INT(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (PropertyID)
);

CREATE TABLE Agents (
AgentID INT(8) AUTO_INCREMENT,
FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
PropertiesManaged VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PhoneNumber VARCHAR (12),
CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (AgentID),
CONSTRAINT PropertiesManaged FOREIGN KEY (PropertyID) REFERENCES Properties (PropertyID)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the column:

```
CREATE TABLE Agents (
    AgentID INT(8) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    PropertiesManaged VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR (12),
    PropertyId INT(8),
----^
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (AgentID),
    CONSTRAINT PropertiesManaged FOREIGN KEY (PropertyID) REFERENCES Properties (PropertyID)    
);
```